# How to trigger if System Settings is changed in android programatically?

Tags: android, gps

My app needs to find the current location based on some time interval which is calculated internally. It will vary each time. During current location check if Internet and GPS both are off then it should show an alert to the user and take the user to Settings page. Once the user turns on the GPS it should call check current location method again.
But is there any way for us to trigger that the user has actually turned on the GPS after he was taken to the settings page?

Answer (score 0):

In [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) you have [`onProviderDisabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onProviderDisabled%28java.lang.String%29) and [`onProviderEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29) which should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this EXACT same task (respond with some Code when the user turns their LOCATION setting ON) and I got it to work wonderfully (albeit in a different way than in the other users answer above) - although their method could work too.. But roughly based on my method, in your case I would simply register a `BroadcastListener` on the fly (when needed) in your Java Code using an `Intent`. Bare in mind you'll need to register for the appropriate `permission` via your `Manifest.xml` file using something like: 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

and (assuming you've registered the `BroadcastReceiver` already in one way or another), something along these lines would be placed in your Receiver:

```
// START OF onReceive METHOD FOR RECEIVER
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    boolean isGpsEnabled;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled;

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);



    // PRIMARY RECEIVER RESPONSE (FOR "PROVIDERS_CHANGED" INTENT-FILTER)
    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Enabled: " + isGpsEnabled + " NetworkLocation Enabled: " + isNetworkEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // START ANOTHER ACTIVITY WHEN GPS IS ENABLED IF YOU WANT
        if (isGpsEnabled) {

            Intent startNextActivity = new Intent(context, YourNextActivity.class);

            // THIS IS NEEDED IF CALLING ACTIVITY FROM OUTSIDE ACTIVITY
            startNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            context.startActivity(startNextActivity);

        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps you out!
Best wishes, and happy coding!